# Факториал в Java

Tags: java, рекурсия

Данный код считает факториал числа n. Почему, чтобы посчитать факториал числа n, нужно n*calcFactorial(n-1)? Почему в Java нельзя просто calcFactorial(n)?

```
public long calcFactorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * calcFactorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: "просто calcFactorial(n)" - это как? У вас есть понимание как работают данный код и рекурсивный алгоритм расчет факториала в целом?

Comment: Если есть идеи, сомнения, мысли, то однозначно надо попробовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это рекурсия. Всякий раз когда функция приходит в блок return она вызывает саму себя, но уже с аргментом n-1. И Так до тех пор пока n не будет раввен 0. n == 0 это крайний случай, тогда функция возвращает 1 и суммирует предыдущие результаты.

Вам стоит больше почитать о том как работает [рекурсия](https://habr.com/ru/post/275813/). Возможно стоит так же почитать о том, что такое факториал если вы задаете такой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял)